# What is the meaning of "unpopular opinion"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, american-english, british-english, phrase-meaning

Please make me understand in easy words that what is the exact meaning of "unpopular opinion". Provide sone example please.

Comment: A dictionary lookup for these two words should serve to clear it up for you.

Comment: @DanBron I did not understand by dictionary that's why I asked here. If someone can clear it easily. As my native language is not English.

Comment: Please [edit] your question (instead of adding comments) to: 1) name the dictionary you used, 2) quote the definitions you read for *each* of the two words, 3) link to that dictionary (if it’s an online one), and 4) describe your understanding of the definitions you quoted in (2), and tell us what’s unclear about them or what questions they left unanswered for you. But honestly, it’d be easier for you to just use a translating dictionary from English to your native language — I can’t imagine there isn’t a very straightforward correspondence.

Answer (score 2):

An **unpopular opinion** in popular culture is a viewpoint or statement that most people are likely to disagree with and which is likely to prove controversial. It's not just a matter of being unpopular in the sense that few people have that opinion: provoking argument or conversation is an important part of it.

The phrase is widely used in popular culture. You can find many on reddit's [r/unpopularopinions](https://www.reddit.com/r/unpopularopinion/) board. In the UK, BBC Radio 1 DJ Greg James does a regular "unpopular opinions" segment where readers and celebrities suggest things which are controversial and argument-provoking. [Here](https://www.facebook.com/bbcradio1/videos/595713491193610/) is a Facebook video, with examples such as "I don't understand why people would do something so horrible as to have cheese with wine", as well as complaints about popular celebrities being overrated (Oprah Winfrey) or heartthrobs being unattractive (Leonardo di Caprio, Shawn Mendes); there are many other videos online.) And since this is Stack Exchange, [here is an XKCD](https://xkcd.com/2184/) about how to have an unpopular opinion on movies: it's easy to claim you hate a movie everyone else likes, but harder to like a movie everyone else hates.